# C# - ConfigurationManager won't refresh static instance

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

I'm successfully setting entries in my app's app.config file. So when I restart the program, `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["something"]` will return the value that was set the last time it was run. But I'm unable to set a value, and then retrieve it again that same way in the same instance. From what I understand, `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")` should reload that section from app.config, so the value I set should be shown the next time I fetch it. But no matter what, it always returns the value it was at when I first started the app.

I could use `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` to get the specific section and get the set value, but I have dependent libraries using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["something"]`, so that part does need to be updated. How can I keep the static instance of ConfigurationManager up to date?

Comment: Actually, you must use `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` to set the values. Please see this post: http://learncsharp.org/how-to-store-and-retrieve-data-in-an-application-or-web-configuration-file/

Comment: Indeed, that's what I'm using to set the values. And when I save the values, they successfully go into the .config file. But refreshing doesn't read the new values.

Comment: It sounds to me like you may have conflicting configuration files. In other words, more than one assembly has a configuration file and `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` is reading from a different one maybe?